# Using Redux state changes to trigger one-time behaviors in disparate web components

Tags: javascript, redux

Say I've got three Web Components - A, B, and C - each keeping an eye on a global redux store. All three observe changes to the state, and respond as they see fit.

Component A fires a redux action, which changes a value in the state: `{ showPopups: true }`

Components B and C notice this value, and each respond by displaying a popup. Now, the behavior expected has been executed, but `showPopups` remains `true`.

Component A fires a second, unrelated redux action - as a result, the state changes, Components B and C notice the `showPopups` value is still `true`, and respond by displaying their popups a second time.

We don't want that - and one easy way to avoid that would be to set `lastShowPopups` inside of Components B and C, compare that last value to the current value, and *only* trigger the popup display if the value *changes* from `false` to `true`.

However, what if Component A fires that first redux action *again*? `showPopups` is already `true`, which means the state doesn't change, which means the popups don't show. We could try to sidestep this by getting tricky about how we set that value - say, we could assign the value as a `new Boolean(1)` instead of `true`. `new Boolean(1)` is truthy, but it is not strictly equal to another `new Boolean(1)`, right?

So it still triggers the state change, which means our components notice that `showPopups` is set to `true`, and... ignore  it, because their internal `lastShowPopups` variable is still `true` as well.

How do we tell Components B and C to only trigger their behavior one time, the first time, not to retrigger when unrelated state changes occur and the old value that triggered the behavior remains unchanged, but to also allow those behaviors to retriggern if the action that precipitates the state value change happens again?

In other words, can you use Redux state changes to trigger one-time behaviors in disparate web components?

Comment: note - this'd be trivial if Component A could fire a CustomEvent that Components B and C would listen to - but in this example, let's assume that they don't have any parents / siblings / children in common, and don't have a convenient way to 'see' one another, apart from what gets put in their shared global Redux store.

Comment: What causes your popups to "go away".? Something in a `setTimeout` I assume.

Comment: The redux state only tells you what **is** right now. So, your popups should always be showing when `showPopups` is true and never be showing when it is false. So if whatever hides or removes your popups would instead set `showPopups` to false, I think you wouldn't have problems like this.

Comment: It sounds like you're suggesting that popups show on showPopups === true, then after a setTimeout, they dispatch another redux action that sets showPopups = false, which they then observe and react to by doing their 'popups go away' behavior?

How would you account for a situation where each popup's wait time before triggering its 'go away' behavior is different - Component B shows for 5 seconds, Component C shows for 10 seconds? Use a different state value for each?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. In that situation, yes I think you would need to store a separate showPopups value for each component. If you do it any other way, its not fully-controlled by state. You could put all of this in the action creator that shows the popups.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: (you should probably do a little writeup to that effect and submit it as an answer so I can mark it as 'accepted')

Comment: yes, good idea. Also, forgot to mention that you would need a thunk middleware to dispatch multiple actions in one creator, but you could also do this inside the popup components in a lifecycle method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since state only describes what **is** at the given moment, you have to handle something like this yourself.

For something like this - popups or notifications, you could dispatch another action inside the same action creator (if you are using thunk middleware like redux-thunk) that creates the popup inside a `setTimeout` that will tear it down again. 
If the popups need to be hidden at different times or according to different criteria, there needs to be value stored in state for each.

So, for the example given, your action creator might look like the below where Component A is only shown then `showPopupA1` is `true` and never when it is `false`. This keeps everything fully-controlled by state and avoids any strange issues on re-renders.

```
export const showPopups = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: SHOW_POPUPS
        })
        // sets showPopupA, showPopupB to true

        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: HIDE_POPUP_A
            })
        }, 5000)
        // sets showPopupA to false

        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: HIDE_POPUP_B
            })
        }, 10000)
        // sets showPopupB to false
    }
}
```

You'll need to use a middleware like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to dispatch multiple actions like this, or dispatch the HIDE_POPUP actions from your popup component in `componentDidMount` or something, this is just a little cleaner.